# how to print comma separated values to rows in excel using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

i have two columns where one column contains id and another column contains comma seperated value. I want to split the comma separated values to rows in excel

For Example

```
id    value
1      a1,a2,a3
2      a1,a2
```

output

```
id    value
1     a1
1     a2
1     a3
2     a1
2     a2
```

is there any formula to do this instead of vba code

Comment: As you want to actually create new rows, there's no standard excel formula you can use to achieve this. You'll need VBA

Comment: What about replacing commas with paragraph marks in the notepad or word? Then you can fill id column more easily.

Comment: As stated by #tebs1200 there is no formula that will do this, but I have VBA code that can, let me know if you want a copy of the code?